# InitializeCriticalSection works in one project, but fails in another

Tags: c++, critical-section

Using Visual Studio 2019 Professional on Windows 10 x64. I have several C++ DLL projects, some of which are multi-threaded. I'm using `CRITICAL_SECTION` objects for thread safety.

In DLL1:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION critDLL1;
InitializeCriticalSection(&critDLL1);
```

In DLL2:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION critDLL2;
InitializeCriticalSection(&critDLL2);
```

When I use critDLL1 with `EnterCriticalSection` or `LeaveCriticalSection` everything is fine in both `_DEBUG` or `NDEBUG` mode. But when I use critDLL2, I get an access violation in 'ntdll.dll' in `NDEBUG` (though not in `_DEBUG`).

After popping up message boxes in `NDEBUG` mode, I was eventually able to track the problem down to the first use of `EnterCriticalSection`.

What might be causing the `CRITICAL_SECTION` to fail in one project but work in others? The [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsection) was not helpful.

**UPDATE 1**

After comparing project settings of DLL1 (working) and DLL2 (not working), I've accidentally got DLL2 working. I've confirmed this by reverting to an earlier version (which crashes) and then making the project changes (no crash!).

This is the setting:

```
Project Properties > C/C++ > Optimization > Whole Program Optimization
```

Set this to `Yes (/GL)` and my program crashes. Change that to `No` and it works fine. What does the `/GL` switch do and why might it cause this crash?

**UPDATE 2**

The excellent answer from @Acorn and comment from @RaymondChen, provided the clues to track down and then resolve the issue. There were two problems (both programmer errors).

PROBLEM 1

The assumption of `Whole Program Optimzation` (wPO) is the MSVC compiler is compiling "the whole program". This is an incorrect assumption for my DLL project which internally consumes a 3rd party library and is in turn consumed by an external application written in Delphi. This setting is set to `Yes (/GL)` by default but should be `No`. This feels like a bug in Visual Studio, but in any case, the programmer needs to be aware of this. I don't know all the details of what `WPO` is meant to do, but at least for DLLs meant to be consumed by other applications, the default should be changed.

PROBLEM 2

Serious programmer error. It was a call into a 3rd party library, which returned a 128-byte ASCII code which was the error:

```
// Before
// m_config::acSerial defined as "char acSerial[21]"
(void) m_pLib->GetPara(XPARA_PRODUCT_INFO, &m_config.acSerial[0]);
EnterCriticalSection(&crit);  // Crash!

// After
#define SERIAL_LEN 20
// m_config::acSerial defined as "char acSerial[SERIAL_LEN+1]"
//...
char acSerial[128];
(void) m_pLib->GetPara(XPARA_PRODUCT_INFO, &acSerial[0]);
strncpy(m_config.acSerial, acSerial, max(SERIAL_LEN, strlen(acSerial)));
EnterCriticalSection(&crit);  // Works!
```

The error, now obvious, is that the 3rd party library did not copy the serial number of the device into the `char*` I provided...it copied 128 bytes into my `char*` stomping over everything contiguous in memory after `acSerial`. This wasn't noticed before because `m_pLib->GetPara(XPARA_PRODUCT_INFO, ...)` was one of the first calls into the 3rd party library and the rest of the contiguous data was mostly NULL at that point.

The problem was never to do with the `CRITICAL_SECTION`. My thanks for Acorn and RaymondChen ... sanity has been restored to this corner of the universe.

Comment: I've never seen it fail in over 20 years...  Do you have some code we can look at?

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but since you're using Visual Studio 2019, I would use the standard C++11/14, etc. thread functions instead of the low-level Windows functions.

Comment: Yes, we need to know where and when these functions are called.  Just two isolated lines doesn't really help.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: Yes, this is the problem. Its a large project.

Comment: Dammit, I've been fiddling with the property pages of the two projects (comparing setting by setting)...and now `critDLL2` can be used without crashing. Will try to back-track, reproduce and report back.

Comment: Not been able to reproduce the crash. I kept a copy of the DLL built about an hour ago and that definitely crashes (AV in `ntdll.dll`), but the DLL built since about 15 minutes ago does not crash. Back-tracking project settings has not reproduced the crash. This feels like a "cache bug" or similar in VS 2019. If I work out what it is, will report back.

Comment: Aha! Bit of progress. I completely deleted (or rather renamed) my entire DLL2 project and brought back yesterday's version which crashes as described in the question (on the first use of `EnterCriticalSection`). Now doing a detailed WinDiff comparison to see what is different. Will report back...

Comment: Getting closer. The only differences where in the project `.vcxproj` files. Added the differences as an update to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your program crashes under WPO (an optimization that assumes that whatever you are compiling is the entire program), it means that either the assumption is incorrect or that the optimizer ends up exploiting some undefined behavior that previously didn't (without the optimization applied), even if the assumption is correct.

In general, avoid enabling optimizations unless you are really sure you know you meet their requirements.

For further analysis, please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: To test this theory, you can try to set a breakpoint on the `InitializeCriticalSection` call in DLL2. Then see if the breakpoint hits. If the debugger says that it cannot set a breakpoint there because "no executable code is associated with this line", then the compiler concluded that the code is not legally reachable and deleted it.

Comment: @Acorn. Thanks. When the DLL project was created, `WPO` was turned on by default and its not a correct assumption for my project. The DLL is consumed by an external application (written in Delphi), and so `WPO` is definitely an optimization too far. Curiously, though, since its a DLL project, why can't the MSVC compiler work that out? There's something interesting going on here and I will try to produce a MRE...

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks for that comment. By making two changes to my `Debug` build, I was able to get it to crash: (1) `C/C++ > General > Debug Information Format = /Zi`, (2) `C/C++ > Optimization > Whole Program Optimization = Yes (/GL)`. Now the debug build crashes, I can step through and find out what is going on. When the `CRITICAL_SECTION` is first initialised, `DebugInfo = 0xffffffff`. I can `EnterCriticalSection(&crit);`. At some point, `DebugInfo` changes to `0x00000000`, then `EnterCriticalSection(&crit);` crashes. The change happens on a call into a 3rd party library, huh?

Comment: Acorn/Raymond: Thanks so much...found the problem! Programmer error - it was the call into the 3rd party library. Their documentation said the call returned a "128-byte ASCII code", but up to the terminating NULL was always far less, so I allocated less than 128 bytes (char serial[21] to be exact). When I called into the library, I compounded this error by giving it a pointer to `serial`, instead of a local 128-byte array which I then copy into `serial`. The library literally pumped 128 bytes (17 chars, NULL, and another 111 NULL bytes), stomping all over my data and critical section.

Comment: Curiously, with `WPO` off, the programmer error is still there...but `EnterCriticalSection` works and `DebugInfo` remains `0xffffffff`. After fixing the programmer error with `char serial[128]; \ LIB-CALL(@serial[0]); \ strncpy(...)` everything works fine. I'll include these details in the question...thanks again!

Comment: @AlainD It was undefined behavior in the end, then (as usual when bugs are only triggered in some conditions). I am glad you found it! :)